# Validating that if the field in integer,Long and double value in java bean validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my spring boot application. I am validating the input request parameters.
I am following the below  guide and validating at the Bean Model level.
https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/

For the **Long** what is the valid annotation which verifies if the input field is of long type?Or can I use any regex pattern if so can anyone help me with  valid  regular expression for **Long** value.

For the **Double** value what is the valid annotation which verifies if the input field is of double type?Or can I use any regex pattern if so can anyone help me with  valid  regular expression for double value.I dont want to use **BigDecimal** as it may break the already existing code.

Comment: A `Long` is of type `Long` and can be converted to `long` using the `longValue()` method. What do you want to validate? I mean if request parameters can not be converted to `Long` they can not be assigned to a `Long` field. You will get a conversion error.

Comment: From request if I send 
{
"long_fieldname" :""
}
Then it should send the error response that the field type is not valid should be a double value.
In short validate if the field is of type double or not

Comment: This kind of validation is built-in, because Java is strongly typed. If you're passing a String in your json, and it is not throwing a validation exception, then there is something that's not working about the validation mechanism. Can you please add some code, so we can better help you?

Comment: I did not add any validation mechanism for the double type and long type...for string types I am getting the expected error response
I could add validations for string types like below
@NotBlank(message = "sample field cannot be null")
 private String sampleField ;

but for long and double could not figure out correct validators.
@Column(name = "longfield")
 private Long longfield;
@Column(name = "doublefield")
 private Double doublefield;

Answer (score 1):

You can do for long by using @Range , @Digits

@Range will have min, max, message
but min and max only takes integer so add `L` at last like this:

```java
@Range(min = 0, max = 4294967298L, message="Count of crystals should be less than 4294967298")
private Long cntOfCrystals;
```

but `@Range` is from `import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Range;` so make sure add this dependency and `@Pattern` won't work for Long and Double